# la clase no se posicionan en el css grid

Tags: css, html5, grid

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
.hero{
    display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 90px 150px 150px 150px;
   grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 60px); 
   /* justify-content: center; */
   grid-gap:10px;
}

.head-hero:nth-last-of-type(1){
   background-color: lightblue;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 20% 60% 10% 10% ;
   grid-template-rows: 60px;
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 6;
   justify-items: center;
   align-items: center;
}
.hero-menu:nth-last-of-type(1){
   background-color: lightcoral;
   grid-row-start:2;
   grid-row-end: 8;
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 2;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-rows: 5% 5% 80% 50% ;
}

.title-section{
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 6;
}

.hero-principal{
    display: grid; 
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 6; 
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 6;
   grid-template-columns:150px 150px 150px;
   grid-template-rows: 8.3% 25% 8.3% 25% 8.3% 25%;
   grid-gap:28px;
}

.card-design{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
}

.post-image{
     margin: 0;
}
.post-image img{
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.post-text{
    background-color: rgba(167, 53, 53, 0.4);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 50%;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: baseline;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.title-text{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text{
    font-size: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>prueba movi</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
        <header class="head-hero">
            <h1 class="title-movie">
                  Movie.tv
            </h1>
            <div class="browser-head">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Busca tu pelicula favorita aqui!">
            </div>
            <div class="user-head">
                <h3 class="name-user">Arturo Becerra</h3>
            </div>
            <picture class="image-profile">
                <img src="los-chicos-del-barrio.jpg" alt="" width="50px" height="50px">
            </picture>
        </header>
        <div class="hero-menu">
            <p>home</p>
            <p>tendring</p>
            <p>like</p>
            <p>ajutes</p>
        </div>
        <section class="hero-principal">
            <h3 class="title-section">
                Mas vistas!
            </h3>
            <div class="hero-card1">
                <a href="" class="card-design">
                    <figure class="post-image">
                        <img src="./los-chicos-del-barrio.jpg" alt="" width="150px" height="100px" >
                    </figure>
                    <div class="post-text">
                        <p>
                            <span class="title-text">
                                Los chicos del barrio
                            </span>
                            <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut itaque delectus dolore numquam nobis unde.</span>        
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="card-design">
                    <figure class="post-image">
                        <img src="./los-chicos-del-barrio.jpg" alt="" width="150px" height="100px" >
                    </figure>
                    <div class="post-text">
                        <p>
                            <span class="title-text">
                                Los chicos del barrio
                            </span>
                            <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut itaque delectus dolore numquam nobis unde.</span>        
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="" class="card-design">
                    <figure class="post-image">
                        <img src="./los-chicos-del-barrio.jpg" alt="" width="250px" height="200px" >
                    </figure>
                    <div class="post-text">
                        <p>
                            <span class="title-text">
                                Los chicos del barrio
                            </span>
                            <span class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut itaque delectus dolore numquam nobis unde.</span>        
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </a>                
        </section>

    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

estoy comenzando en el desarrollo web y en estos momento estoy aprendiendo a utilizar **css grid**, estoy realizando una prueba del curso donde creo una grid principal y dentro de cada casilla principal agrego un subgrid pero al momento de posicionar las grillas la clase **.title-section** no toman el grid de ninguna manera, ya he intentado mirando y modificando cada línea de código y no he encontrado cual es el problema organice las filas y columnas de tal manera que cada articulo tomara su posición pero tampoco, agradecería mucho su ayuda la verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Para poderte ayudar debes proveer un [mcve], si tienes dudas lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

He estado mirando tu código... el h3 de las clase ".title-section" ya esta ocupando desde la columna 1 hasta la 6. Si le añades color de fondo y altura lo podrás ver, si lo quieres centrado añádele text-align: center.

Te lo dejo en este snippet

```css
.hero-principal{
    display: grid; 
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 6; 
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 6;
    grid-template-columns:150px 150px 150px;
    grid-template-rows: 8.3% 25% 8.3% 25% 8.3% 25%;
    grid-gap:28px;
}

.title-section{
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-column-end: 6;
   
   /* Css nuevo */
   background-color: lightgreen; 
   height: 26px;
   text-align: center;
}
```

También creo que sería mejor declarar primero el contenedor grid "hero-prinicipal" y luego el elemento que quieres posicionar en el grid ".title-section".

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado :D